# Gallery Intent conflicts with Work Profile

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-gallery, google-workspace

I have a code that opens a gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

this is working when app is installed on my own but when it is included as a Work Profile under GSuite the apps shows. `No apps can perform this action`

what is the probable cause?